# Find and return the ID of the current view

Tags: android, layout, view

I'm trying to set up a "close to start" button in a game. The game takes the user from view to view like a maze. The user could be on any view, but I want a way to get them back to the start screen. Is there a way to find and return the ID of the current view for my findViewByID? I've found a I've tried the following code in various forms:

```
OnClickListener closetomain = new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

     int currentid = v.findFocus().getId();

     RelativeLayout hideme = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(currentid);
     hideme.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);
//         RelativeLayout showme = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.startLayout);
//         showme.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it turns out I should have given each close button the same ID and used theisenp's suggestion for the simplest code (well, that I could understand).  It also turns out that I should have started by putting each level/layout in its own activity. You live and you learn I guess. Below is my XML and java. It may not be the elegant solution but I'm not sure I care all that much as long as it works.

```
        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/closeButton"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="@drawable/close" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:onClick="closetomain">
    </ImageButton>
```

And here's my Java:

```
public void closetomain(View view) {
switch(view.getId()) {
    case R.id.closeButton:
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to retrieve the id of the current view?  Is it just so that you can set it's visibility to GONE?  If so, there are probably better ways of implementing that same functionality.

Instead of just changing the layout with setContentView(), it would probably be a better idea to have the Start Screen be its own separate activity.  When you are in any of the "maze views" you could simply use an intent to start your home screen activity like this

```
Intent startScreenIntent = new Intent(this, StartScreen.Class);
startActivity(startScreenIntent);
```

Then you won't have to worry about finding id's or changing visibilities, plus the code is cleaner, because it separates the code for your Maze levels and your Start Menu.

Comment: That sounds like a great idea if I had thought of it a while ago. Unfortunately, I'm pretty new at this and very far along to refactor my code like that.

Comment: In that case, what have you been using to switch between screens?  If your start screen layout is stored in R.layout.main, can't you just use setContentView(R.layout.main) ?

If you have switched your content view away from the maze view, you shouldn't have to worry about setting the view to GONE.

Comment: I tried setContentView... but get: View$1.onClick(View) line: 2059 
ImageButton(View).performClick() line: 2408 
View$PerformClick.run() line: 8816 
ViewRoot(Handler).handleCallback(Message) line: 587 
ViewRoot(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 92 
Looper.loop() line: 123 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4627 
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method] 
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 521 
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 868 
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 626 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line

Comment: After you change the content view, any references to the old layout are invalid.  You are most likely trying to access some element of the old layout in the performClick() function for your image button.  What type of error are you getting?  Is it a NullPointerException, or something else?

Comment: I'm not getting an error, just what I included above. I see what you're saying so I'll take another look at the code.

Comment: Where did you find the "View$1.onClick(View) line:..." message then if it wasn't some sort of error?  Was it in the logcat?  I know that you've written most of your code like this, but honestly, you'll save yourself a lot of time and effort in the long run if you use activities.